# How to publish webpack on Vite properly

Tags: vite, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Im trying to publish locally a webpack on Vite to test micro front ends, but when I run my host app, it doesn't find the remoteEntry.js, and thats because when I try to access my remoteEntry.js, it doesn't exist. Does anyone know why?

This is my vite.conf on the remote

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
// https://vitejs.dev/config/

// vite.config.js
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 8080,
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: "myLib",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      // Modules to expose
      exposes: {
        "./Counter": "./src/components/Counter.vue",
      },
      remotes: {},
      shared: ["vue"],
    }),
  ],
});
```

And this is the config on the remote side:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 8081,
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: "myApp",
      remotes: {
        myLib: "http://localhost:8080/assets/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: ["vue"],
    }),
  ],
});
```

When i try to access my dependencies on the host side, this error pops on the console:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:8080/assets/remoteEntry.js

Thank you very much

Comment: I have the same problem, could you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, still waiting haha

Answer (score 1):

The **remoteEntry.js** file is not built if you are starting your remote server by running the `vite` command. To get around this you can run `vite preview` to launch a development server using the actual bundle.

The docs mention this briefly here: https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation#vite-dev-mode

They suggest you run `vite build --watch` if you want your changes to hot update. You can also specify a development build by adding the `--mode=development` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue, I fixed like custom domain. you can add hosts domain and run your code. example

For Windows
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
add below

```
127.0.0.1 client1.test.com
```

and you can change in host vite.config.ts `localhost` to `client1.test.com`

now it will work

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue, but I'm using nx in addition to vite. My problem is that `vite build` will generate `remoteEntry.js` in the `dist` directory, but it doesn't run the remote server (as mentioned in the docs). But, while `vite preview` does start a server for the remote, and it serves out of the `dist` directory, it triggers a build again, but in dev mode, which doesn't seem to use the `vite-plugin-federation` plugin...because it overwrites the `dist` directory with the same set of files I see when running in dev mode (i.e. it doesn't produce `remoteEntry.js`). This may be an nx thing, as `nx preview` defaults to building with the development configuration. If I update nx's project.json to use the production configuration, it does produce `remoteEntry.js` and serves the project successfully.

So, [pdro_99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16552992/pdro-99), first check your `dist` directory while running in preview mode, and see if there is actually a `remoteEntry.js`. Second, try running `vite preview` in `production` mode, to see if that'll produce the module federation files.